# How to display the selected value in select option field from the json object fetched form server angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have fetched a `json` object with the list of countries. And now i want to display the selected name of the country in the select option box. I've tried different ways but there always keep showing the blank value.

Note:`countries` is the `json object` having the list of countries with key value pair. It used to display the select option in the view. And `tabs[0].data.country` is the value of country id which is to be selected.

Some of the codes i have tried:
Code to display the selected country name:
[image]

Code to display the select option in View:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: show, what you have done so far..

Comment: Sure! I will update the question with some screenshots!

Comment: Search engines cannot read the screenshot code blocks in your question.  Volunteers cannot copy-paste your screenshot code.  Please edit your question to replace the screenshot with actual text.  Please never use screenshots to present code in a Stack Exchange question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally, here is the snippet that solved my problem.

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <form name="myForm">
     <label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label>
     <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
        ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id" ng-model="data.selectedOption">
     </select>
   </form>
</div>
```

**js**

```
angular.module('defaultValueSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     availableOptions: [
       {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
       {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
       {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
     ],
     selectedOption: {id: '3', name: 'Option C'} //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
     };
 }]);
```

For more information you can go to this [link](http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/)

[Also another useful tutorial here](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1196/angularjs-dropdown-select-value-text-multiple-values-with-demo)

Answer (score 0):

Convert you json object into an array of objects first, and then you do something like

```
    <select name="countries" id="contries" ng-model="vm.country">
      <option ng-repeat="country in vm.countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

Just loop over them and pick what you want from the list. Full documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! in fact i already did this one. I was wondering how to display the selected value from the list. Also I looked through the link you have given but i'm not so clear about this particular problem.